# The library is not added to the git via the git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I added the GLFV library to the project, through the git subtree, but this warning came out "It looks like either your git installation or yourgit-subtree installation is broken". Several reasons have also been described why this may be:

- If `git --exec-path` does not print the correct path to your git install directory, then set the GIT_EXEC_PATH environment variable to the correct directory.
- Make sure that your `git-core \ git-subtree` file is either in your PATH or in your git exec path (`C: / Program Files / Git / mingw64 / libexec / git-core`).
- You should run git-subtree as `git core \ git-subtree`, not as `git-core \ git-subtree`.

I checked the link to the library is correct, the file "git-subtree" is there, why then the error pops up.

Comment: Same issue here, which is new from my last push about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the git subtree installation is broken issue is with Git for Windows.

I was able to download an older version from: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.31.0.windows.1/Git-2.31.0-64-bit.exe

This fixed the issue for me while we await a fix. There's an [issue on Git for Window's GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3260) for the git subtree error.

I got the below error:

## It looks like either your git installation or your git-subtree installation is broken.

```
It looks like either your git installation or your git-subtree installation is broken.

Tips:
 - If `git --exec-path` does not print the correct path to
   your git install directory, then set the GIT_EXEC_PATH
   environment variable to the correct directory.
 - Make sure that your `git-core\git-subtree` file is either in your
   PATH or in your git exec path (`C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`).
 - You should run git-subtree as `git core\git-subtree`,
   not as `git-core\git-subtree`.
```

If you wouldn't mind, please accept this as the answer.

Comment: The good news is, v2.33 was released couple of days ago and I tested it fixed the issue. you can get it from https://git-scm.com/download/win.